# appwidget update textview on 12am everyday

Tags: java, android, android-widget, android-appwidget

I have an app widget and I want to update the text view everyday on 12 am,I don't know what to do

**here is my widget provider class:**

```
public class WidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        for(int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {

            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.app_widget);

            LocalDate birthday = LocalDate.of(2020, 10, 16);
            LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
            long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(birthday,now) + 1;

            views.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_days, Long.toString(days));

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId,views);
        }

    }
}
```

**Manifest part:**

```
 <receiver android:name=".widget.WidgetProvider">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/appwidget_info"/>
        </receiver>
```

**and my appwidget_info file:**

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/app_widget"
    android:minHeight="110dp"
    android:minWidth="250dp"
    android:resizeMode="none"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="3600000"
    android:previewImage="@drawable/widget_preview"
    android:widgetCategory="home_screen">
</appwidget-provider>
```

Comment: Then what's the issue?

Comment: issue is i dont know how

Comment: Try `WorkManager` https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager